# Jenkins API: list all available labels

Tags: jenkins-api

In the Jenkins API it's possible to query for information regarding a specific label (`MY_LABEL`) by invoking:

`https://JENKINS_URL/label/MY_LABEL/api/json?pretty=true`

Question: Is there any endpoint that could list ALL the available labels on a Jenkins server?

Answer (score 0):

Found out one way to do it. Interpret the output of `JENKINS_URL/computer/api/json?pretty=true`

Comment: Are there any better ways?

Comment: Did you find a better way to get the list of labels @Niclas ?